# Attaching workflow to node using rule

Tags: 7, rules, workflows

Is there anyway I can set workflow dynamically using rule. Basically I need to setup workflow for given article only when someone flagged that article.

So can I setup some kind of rule that when an article is flagged, initialize workflow for that node and assign it to one of the workflow state?

-- Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set up a workflow that includes a default "no_workflow" state?  Use rules to automatically set all nodes to the "no_workflow" state upon creation.  Then, when a node is flagged, use rules to set it to the appropriate state.  That way, all nodes are subject to the workflow, but by default they don't move through the states until they are flagged.

Comment: But in that case a workflow tab would be still visible to the author. I don't want that tab to be shown when the article is not in the moderation state.

Comment: You could write a hook to hide the workflow tab when the node is in the "no_workflow" state.  I think that would be a lot easier to code than a rule that initializes a workflow arbitrarily when content is flagged.

Comment: Ok, I'll give a try. Thanks for your help and time.